# Why this experiment to detect 'which hole the electron went through' doesn't work?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

In Feynman Lectures on Physics Volume 3,(1-8 The uncertainty principle),

He talks about an experiment to detect which hole the electron went through in the double slit experiment without disturbing the interference pattern.

The experiment goes like this...

The double slit experiment setup but the Wall (plate) with the holes is mounted on rollers so that it can move freely up and down (See the figure).
When an electron reaches the detector, it get deflected and imparts a momemtum on the plate. If the electron went through the upper hole, the plate will move up or vice versa.

So by just observing the motion of the plate, we can tell which hole the electron went through without breaking the Interference pattern.

Feynman explains that this is not possible because when the electron hits the plate it changes its position randomly and smears out the interference pattern.
[image]

**But my question is...**

What if we put an electronic or mechanical mechanism on the plate so that if the plate moves, our system will bring it back to the initial position so that the Interference pattern is not disturbed?

We can increase the accuracy of this experiment to arbitrary degree and measure the position and momentum of the electron simultaneosly.

I know this will break the uncertainty principle, so where have I gone wrong?

Can anyone please explain why this setup doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

> What if we put an electronic or mechanical mechanism on the plate so that if the plate moves, our system will bring it back to the initial position so that the Interference pattern is not disturbed?

It's too late.  The electron has already interacted with the plate.  When that happened, the electron's momentum changed from what it would have been with a fixed plate.  That (imprecise) momentum change modifies the target that is reached by the electron afterward.  The interference pattern will not appear.

Comment: The electron are fired one at a time. I meant what if the system resets after each electron has went through..?

Comment: Resetting doesn't help.  The problem isn't so much that the location of the opening isn't the same with each collision, it's that the opening is movable at all.  This means the momentum of the electron changes an unknown amount during the collision.  This imprecise momentum will prevent the pattern from developing.  You've learned which slot it went through, but lost the interference pattern.

Comment: hmm....But I still can't understand how the plate being movable can disturb the interference pattern.

Comment: <the momentum of the electron changes an unknown amount during the collision>How does this destroy the interference?

Comment: Because it changes the angle the electron is deflected by the hole.  If the plate is immobile, the angle in must be the angle out.  But if some momentum is given to the plate, the angle changes.  If a variable amount of momentum is given to the plate, then the reflected angle is variable as well.  The target is no longer perfectly aligned and the interference is smeared out.